# SASS task in gulp with sourceComments: 'map' produces 'Assertion failed'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp

I have a web app I'm developing using AngularJS, D3, Pixi.js, and gulp as a build system. It all works great together, except `gulp-sass`. Here's the relevant code:

```
gulp.task('sass-dev', ['clean-dev'], function() {
  return gulp.src( cfg.appFiles.rootSass )
    .pipe( sass({ errLogToConsole: true }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest( cfg.buildDir+cfg.destDirs.css  ) )
    .pipe( livereload( server ) );
});
```

`cfg` is just a variable that has predefined globs. If I make the third line

```
 .pipe( sass({ errLogToConsole: true, sourceComments: 'map' }))
```

by adding the mapping of the source (useful for debugging), I get the following fatal error.

```
Assertion failed: (val->IsString()), function _NanGetExternalParts, file ../node_modules/nan/nan.h, line 1725.
Abort trap: 6
```

On my colleague's computer, it works perfectly with or without mapping. On mine, it fails every time with the source comments mapped, and works perfectly without mapping. Both computers are iMacs running the latest version of `node` (`npm`), `bower`, and `OS X`.

Any idea what could be causing this? Issue in `gulp` or `gulp-sass` itself?

Comment: What version of Sass is being used on both systems?

Comment: @cimmanon We're using gulp-sass 0.7.1

Comment: First: Please read the docs: [https://github.com/sass/node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass). Second: you need the file param.

Comment: The files are what is being piped into the sass command. And I have read the docs. Please see https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass since we're using gulp as a build system. Example from their docs:

`var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./scss/*.scss').pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});`

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue -except on ubuntu.  Anyone got a solution or workaround yet?

Comment: These options worked for me. `{ errLogToConsole: true, sourceComments: 'map', sourceMap: 'sass' }`. There's always seems to be something weird going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These options worked for me.

```
{ errLogToConsole: true, sourceComments: 'map', sourceMap: 'sass' }.
```

There's always seems to be something weird going on.

Comment: You're right. Once I added the sourceMap comment too, it worked seemingly without reason. Oh well!

Comment: I'm getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) in Ubuntu using these options any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea. No Ubuntu to check on.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cause was an empty scss file. Adding a comment to the file, or removing the scss file, solved this problem