# Gulp-generated source maps don't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sass, gulp, source-maps

Apart from enabling `source maps` in Chrome, in my gulpfile.js I use `errLogToConsole: true, sourceComments: 'map', sourceMap: 'sass'` as arguments when calling `sass` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24443990/871404):

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('../assets/styles/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
  .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true, sourceComments: 'map', sourceMap: 'sass'}))
  .pipe(autoprefixer())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/styles'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});
```

Yet `SCSS` content still doesn't show up in DevTools. Why?

Note: source map comments do show up in compiled CSS as shown in screenshot below

[image]

Comment: did you add `gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'sass']);` to Gulp’s default tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure which version of `gulp-sass` you're using that was allowing you to pass these sourceMaps options, but using the latest version, they leverage [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps) instead, allowing you to do something like this:

```js
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('../assets/styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/styles'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})
```

By default it will inline your sourcemaps to the output file, but you can specify a file in the `sourcemaps.write` function, to change this behavior.